# How to get the nth text after a delimiter in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following values

```
animal_cat
dog_bone_husky
```

i want to get only the second text after the first underscore

in this case i only want to get cat for B1

and bone for B2

im using this formula

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("_",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","_",3))+1,255))
```

the problem is for my second row it also gets all the text after the first delimiter
in this case it shows bone_husky

is there a way to only get the second text?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is (multiple ways). For example as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=2]")
```

Comment: Wow, this looks ridiculusly complex for such a simple task.

Answer (score 3):

Say **A1** contains:

alpha_beta_gamma_delta_zeta_eta_theta

to get *alpha* use:    `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),1*999-998,999))`
to get *beta* use:     `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))`
to get *gamma* use:  `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),3*999-998,999))`
to get *delta* use:     `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999))`
to get *zeta* use:     `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),5*999-998,999))`

etc.

If you enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

in **B1** and copy across, you will get the equivalent to *Text-to-Columns* in formula form:

[image]

Based on:

[Rick Rothstein](https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/333-Get-Field-from-Delimited-Text-String)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps also worth noting is the `TEXTSPLIT` excel function

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7

e.g. for input-strings with underscore in column `A` ("Input" in my e.g.), use formula `=TEXTSPLIT(A2,"_",,,,)` in column `B` ("output" in my e.g.) and fill down.

Then leverage the nth output column, the second in your case (column `C` in my e.g.)

[image: TEXTSPLIT in Action]

You can use `INDEX` to get this Nth item, e.g.

```
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2,,"_"),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty version:

```
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_"),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1 =TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","",3))+1,255))    ~~> cat
A2 =TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","",3))+1,255))    ~~> bone
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**